# Rudin's Definition of Diameter

Tags: analysis

The definition 3.9 on PMA by Rudin says

> Let $E$ be a subset of a metric space $X$, and let $S=\{d(p,q) \mid p,q\in E\}$. Then $\sup E$ is called the diameter of $E$.

Should diameters be only defined for bounded sets? Or is the author defining the diameter of an unbounded set to be $+\infty$?
If the latter, are the discussions that follow later consistent to his definition of diameters? For example, right after definition 3.9, the author says

> If $(p_n)$ is a sequence in $X$ and if $E_N$ consists of the points $p_N, p_{N+1}, \ldots$, it is clear from the preceding two definitions that $(p_n)$ is Cauchy if and only if $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\text{diam}E_N=0$.

If $(p_n)$ is not bounded, then the diameter of $E_N$ is $+\infty$. So in this case, how do we interpret the sequence $(\text{diam}E_N)$?

Comment: Every Cauchy sequence is necessarily bounded.

Comment: well I know that. but in the discussion after definition 3.9, the $(p_n)$ is not assumed to be Cauchy to begin with. so how do we interpret $(\text{diam}E_N)$ is $(p_n)$ is not bounded.

Comment: If $(p_n)$ isn't bounded, then it isn't a Cauchy sequence and $E_N$ doesn't approach $0$, so the equivalence in your second quotation is correct in this case.

Comment: Yes if the $p_n$ aren't bounded then the diameter of $E_N$ is always infinite. This is a sequence in the "extended real numbers" $\mathbf{R} \cup \{ -\infty, \infty\}$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I know that if $(p_n)$ is not bounded, then certainly the diameter of $E_N$ does not approach $0$, but in that case, what is it that does not approach $0$? The sequence whose element is all $+\infty$? Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Unless diameters are somehow required to be real numbers and not $+\infty$, I don't see anything wrong about a sequence whose terms are all $+\infty$,

Comment: Given the circumstances & quotations, it seems highly plausible that, _according to Rudin_, unbounded sets may also have a diameter (which is then $+\infty$). If $(p_n)_n$ satisfies $\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\mathop{\rm diam}(E_N)=0$ then all $E_N$ must be bounded, including $E_0=\{p_0,\ldots,p_n,\ldots\}$.